# php not executing in sub directories / php only working in root directory

Tags: php, web, include

I am refurbishing a website for a friend, e.g. making it more easy to program/maintain.
The server is running PHP 5.6 and in order to make life easier for me I wanted to uses php's *include* function to easily include stuff like the head or menu in every web page.
The file structure I use is *index.php* in the */* directory and e.g. *history.php* in */pages*. The files I am including e.g *head.php* lie in */php*.

My problem is that in *index.php*

```
<?php include ('php/head.php'); ?>
```

perfectly executes and includes the designated file but in all sub directories such as */pages* the same php code in *history.php* just doesn't execute at all leaving me with a blank line in the source code. I figured that this has to do with my PHP config or that said might be wrong, but I couldn't find the issue. I also tried calling the tech support of my web hosting provider but although they told me that everything should be working now I still get a beautiful blank line.

I've been searching for a solution to my problem for quite some days now, but I sadly haven't had any luck so far.
Hope the community can help

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could use `set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/' )` to set the include path before using `include` or `require` so the actual path is correctly set

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!! 
Thanks so much!
This community is just plain and simple awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `include_path` to the full path then no matter in which sub-directory you have scripts they will always use the full path to the required file.

```
<?php
    /* If you set this on every page the path will always be correct */
    set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/php/' );
    include( 'functions.php' );

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Include PHP files</title>
        <?php
            include( 'head.php' );
        ?>
    <body>
        <?php
            include( 'menu.php' );
        ?>

        <!--
            regualar html,javascript etc
        -->

        <?php
            include( 'footer.php' );
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll certainly try what you suggested, but I think it's not a file path issue.
I'll let you know how it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply a file paths issue? If you're in a sub-map, then the path to `head.php` will be different:

`<?php include ('../php/head.php'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think it's not a file path issue. 
I'll try your solution anyways and let you know whether it worked.